# C# Call function in while loop every X seconds without blocking loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, nonblocking

I have a program in C# and I am using a while loop to read lines from a file. I want to be able to display the line number every 5 seconds or so without slowing the while loop down, this is so the user can see how far they are. Any ideas how to do this?

**CODE**

```
    try
    {
        // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
        // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\wamp64\www\brute-force\files\antipublic.txt"))
        {
            String line;
            int lines = 0;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
            // the file is reached.
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:/users/morgan/desktop/hash_table.txt"))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(CreateMD5(line)+':'+line);
                    lines++;
                }
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time taken: {0}s", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Let the user know what went wrong.
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Run file reading code in background thread and send notification to UI thread.

Comment: Couldn't a simple `if (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds % 5 == 0)  Console.WriteLine(lines + " lines read so far...");` after `lines++` in your while loop work?

Comment: Simple Console.WriteLine every 5 seconds won't significally slow down the loop. Or you can use Task.Run

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) class to achive this. Just look at the MSDN example on how to initalize the class.

You could create a "DoWork" method for the BackgroundWorker with a ReportProgress call like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"path"))
    {
        String line;
        int lines = 0;

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("path"))
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                file.WriteLine(CreateMD5(line)+':'+line);
                worker.ReportProgress(lines++);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To display the progress you simply can use Console.WriteLine() in the ProgressChanged event.

Comment: The MSDN documentation states that the ProgressChanged event handler executes on the thread that created the BackgroundWorker. DoWork should run on a different thread than the created instance of the BackgroundWorker.